# jquery colorbox image border

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm developing a site using zenphoto with the colorbox plugin. Both great and have got me 99% of the way there.

Two pretty minor snags for the slideshow on this page.....
http://whatiswordpress.co.uk/rural/dsc_0118.jpg.php

1. Can I remove the thin black border around the full size image used in the slideshow and when you enlarge the photo.
2. Can I increase the Opacity of the #cboxOverlay. I can load a background image, specify a color but whatever I do the opacity stays at a default level 0.8

I think the configuration is complicated by my lack of skill and the fact that I'm trying to manage it through zenphoto which i am not expert at either. :(

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1):

> Can I remove the thin black border around the full size image used in the slideshow and when you enlarge the photo

Yes, remove the following line from `colorbox.css`:

```
#cboxLoadedContent {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    padding: 1px; /* <-- Remove this */
}
```

---

> Can I increase the Opacity of the #cboxOverlay. I can load a background image, specify a color but whatever I do the opacity stays at a default level 0.8

There is an `opacity` setting you can use:

```
$(".colorbox").colorbox({
    inline: true,
    href: "#imagemetadata",
    close: 'close',
    opacity: 1.0
});
```